# Django Debug Toolbar BaseConnectionHandler.all() error

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I am using docker and the debug toolbar gives the following error:

```
BaseConnectionHandler.all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initialized_only'
```

I wrote the following code in the settings.py file :

```
if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE += [
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    ]

    INSTALLED_APPS += [
        'debug_toolbar',
    ]

    import os
    import socket
    hostname, _, ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
    INTERNAL_IPS = [ip[: ip.rfind(".")] + ".1" for ip in ips] + ["127.0.0.1", "10.0.2.2"]
```

I wrote the following code in the urls.py file :

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For some reason `django-debug-toolbar==3.5.0` broke backward compatability with Django lower than 4.1b1.

In 3.5.0 next changes were added:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/commit/4b77ec74f2d326013d715453d7a2219e574c3f6a#diff-72ecd973e54107d746eff0947206cbdbe24cbb3c42216b00615e64d49ca70d73R216-R217

But those changes need this changes in Django 4.1b1 to work:
https://github.com/django/django/commit/4f92cf87b013801810226928ddd20097f6e4fccf#diff-dbe1d4538efcca9f9a6157d5d3de919e0844835a7ccc698bb8c5d4a9eb06e274R75-R81

**Fix the version of django-debug-toolbar to 3.4.0** before issue is solved. Opened issue in github:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/1645

UPD: **Django 3.2.4+ will also work** and thats probably better solution.

Comment: Thanks bro, I installed `pip install django-debug-toolbar == 3.4.0` and it works